# Elasticsearch Query String Query with @ symbol and wildcards

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I defined a custom analyzer that I was surprised not built-in.

```
analyzer": {
    "keyword_lowercase": {
        "type": "custom",
        "filter": [
            "lowercase"
        ],
        "tokenizer": "keyword"
    }
}
```

Then my mapping for this field is:

```
"email": {
    "type": "string",
    "analyzer": "keyword_lowercase"
}
```

This works great. (http://.../_analyze?field=email&text=me@example.com) ->

```
"tokens": [
    {
        "token": "me@example.com",
        "start_offset": 0,
        "end_offset": 16,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 1
    }
]
```

Finding by that keyword works great. http://.../_search?q=me@example.com yields results.

The problem is trying to incorporate wildcards anywhere in the Query String Query. http://.../_search?q=*me@example.com yields **no** results. I would expect results containing emails such as "me@example.com" and "some@example.com".

It looks like elasticsearch performs the search with the default analyzer, which doesn't make sense. Shouldn't it perform the search with each field's own default analyzer?

I.E. [http://.../_search?q=email:*me@example.com](http://...//_search?q=email:*me@example.com) returns results because I am telling it which analyzer to use based upon the field.

Can elasticsearch not do this?

Comment: Can you post your query that uses query_string? It may be that you're not telling elasticsearch which field to search - if so it will use the **_all** field, which is an automatically generated combination of all the fields and uses the standard analyser.

Comment: the _search?q= is a query string query. See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html#_parameters_4 Yes, it uses _all. So, from what you said, it is as I figured. It uses the standard analyzer for all fields, not the each field's default analyzer.

Comment: to add on wildcard queries are not analyzed as a result they do not match in the _all field.

Comment: Ooh, I need to use the full query search query (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) and set analyze_wildcard to true. This fixes my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Set `analyze_wildcard` to `true`, as it is `false` by default.

Comment: Does this solution work for a query containing the "+" symbol. For exemple , I search "HTC One M9+". Thanks :)